# How to conduct Rails model validation witih or condition?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have three fields in my model — name, first_name, and last_name.   would like to have a validation rule in my model that causes a save to fail if the “name” field is empty unless either the first_name or last_name field is not empty.  SOoI tried

```
validates_presence_of :name, :unless => !:first_name.empty? or !:last_name.empty?
```

but this doesn’t work.  I get the error below

```
undefined method `validate' for true:TrueClass
```

What is the proper way to write the validation rule above?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation).

You can write the rule by defining a separate method for it:

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, unless: :firstname_or_surname?

  def firstname_or_surname?
    firstname.present? || surname.present?
  end
end
```

Or you can use a Proc to define it inline:

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true,
    unless: Proc.new { |a| a.firstname.present? || a.surname.present? }
end
```